# Ajax dataReady display customized alert through data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how can we customize the data object to display: The email address has already been registered! via javascript alert.
data gets from the servlet a boolean, right now it displays true or false if the email already is in the database.

```
 $('#emailInput').on('change', function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "Controller",
                cache: false,
                dataType: "text",
                data: "command=checkEmail&email=" + $(this).val(),
                success: dataReady

            });
        });


        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.log-out').fadeIn(200);
        });
    });

    function dataReady(data) {
        alert("Data: " + data);

        if (data == true){
            alert(data);
            $("#emailExists").html("The email address has already been registered!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this I suposse.

```
if (data == true){
    alert("The email address has already been registered!");
    $("#emailExists").html("The email address has already been registered!");
}
```

Anyway you are sending an AJAX request in any change on the text input, this is not a ver good job, too many requests, I'd check the lenght or somethig else.

Comment: The function return true or false correctly?... The other function looks fine.

Comment: we are checking in the backend if this email already exists and if it already exist data is true and it should display already exist. but we are only allowed to make a customer with unique email

Comment: The backend return true or "true"? .. Because there are differents. emailExists is a valid id?

Comment: found out why. when working with servlets. I used the PrintWriter and used out.println but should be out print - it should not make new lines